# Git Bash está sugerindo salvar no disco removível

Tags: git, github

O Git Bash já inicia no disco removível, e todos os comandos que precisa criar alguma pasta ele manda pra esse endereço que aparentemente é o padrão.

Gostaria de saber se tem algum comando global para setar a pasta de trabalho que ele irá utilizar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para definir o local de início do Bash faça o seguinte:

Clique com o direito no ícone do Git Bash e vá em propriedades. Na guia atalho, campo `iniciar em:` informe o local a ser iniciado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas eu, particularmente, prefiro deixar isso não configurado e usar o menu de contexto do próprio Windows. Por exemplo: vá na pasta que você deseja e clique com o botão direito. 
Depois é só selecionar `Git Bash here`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado pela ajuda!